# Is .sln file required by Visual Studio for ASP.NET 5 project? Can it just use Global.json?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

In a ASP.NET 5 project Visual Studio creates a `SLN` file. There is also a `global.json` file which my understanding was the core solution file.

Is `SLN` file just for VS support? Can you open a solution in VS without using `SLN` file?

I assume non VS tooling ignores the `SLN` file as it is folder based?

Comment: I see that you posted many question which goes in the same direction. I find the questions interesting, but I don't full agree with already accepted answer. If you want I can post my answer too, where I describe my point of view more detailed.

Comment: Yup would be definitely interested to hear!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm aware, the `SLN` is a 100% Visual Studio Tooling concept.

You can still create applications, run/compile/publish them without this file. That's how Visual Studio Code does it and that's how you would do it in Sublime/Atom or any other editors.

**UPDATE:**

I've read reports that Visual Studio can open `global.json` and `project.json` file without their respective sln/xproj file present.

Comment: Is there anyway I can delete that file and still open the solution in Visual Studio? Alternatively if someone else started a project outwith VS?

Comment: Not really... Visual Studio still need those stupid solution files but I don't see any need for them really. Just another fluf that might be removed in the future. Just like One ASP.NET did away with multiple `ProjectGuid` per web projects.

Comment: Seems bizarre - MS has gone so far with being open source/cross plat - that you can make projects that their core IDE can't open. Maybe there is a way to create a SLN file from the project so VS can open it

Comment: To be fair... look at the `xproj` file. Tell me what you see inside. Compare that to a `csproj` of an [tag:asp.net-MVC-5] project. As far as I see it, that file isn't even needed. That file is only there for Visual Studio Tooling if you want my opinion. You could exclude it from a Git repository and never encounter a problem until it gets to a Windows-Visual-Studio-using developer.

Comment: I totally love the new ASP.NET so much better. I am just worried about compatibility between me/clients etc. It would same the safest bet is to create it in VS and then it is always an option. Will ask a question about that

Comment: But here's the thing. Visual Studio is a beast. A monster of a software. You can't change everything in 1-2 years. If I was edging my bet... I would probably think that since so much has been taken out of the `csproj` file to make the `xproj` that at some point there might be no need for an xproj file anyway. Pure speculation on my side. See my blog post about the subject: http://blog.decayingcode.com/post/microsoft-open-source-and-the-big-ship

Comment: Compatibility between ASP.NET 4.X and ASP.NET 5 is a non issue. You are not updating, you are changing framework. Keep it like this in your mind and it will be easier to explain it. It's like going from ASP Classic to ASP.NET 1.0. Lots of change. Hard to migrate anyway.

Comment: Understand that - but if I start a project in Visual Studio Code and my clients want to use VS with that project where does that leave them?

Comment: That would warrant another question but the simple answer is create the basic project with whatever tool you need. If you need the `xproj`, auto-gen them. They are quite easy to understand: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/samples/1.0.0-beta7/HelloMvc/HelloMvc.xproj

Comment: Added some info. It seems that it's possible to open global.json and project.json without their sln/xproj. Can you try creating a new solution, delete all sln/xproj file and try to open it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I find your question very interesting, but I find incorrect to compare `.sln` file with `global.json` or old `.xproj` file with `project.json` because there have not the same goals. Moreover I want to mention some other important files like `package.json`, `bower.json` (which are visible if one click on "Show All" button of the solution) and an important `launchSettings.json` file, which one find in `Properties` (see [the documentation](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html) for more details).

It's clear that the format of `.sln` file and `.xproj` file have to be changed and simplified in the future. On the other side, there are some goals of old files, which one have to take in considerations. I want just mention someone.

First of all, it's important not only to build the code, but to debug or to start the target with some parameters. If I develop Web Api component, for example, then I can need to build it and then to test some methods (actions) by opening the URLs like `http://localhost:4745/api/product`. Configuring the App URL in GUI of Visual Studio will change the file `Properties\launchSettings.json` and to include something like

```json
"iisSettings": {
  "windowsAuthentication": false,
  "anonymousAuthentication": true,
  "iisExpress": {
    "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:4745/api/product",
    "sslPort": 0
  }
}
```

inside.

The next typical problem. I want to test, whether the new component (the new Web Api) work correctly with my old Visual Studio Project. I can, for example,  create new Web Site or another Project, which call the Web Api from JavaScript (HTML page which use `jQuery.ajax` fox example).

The old `.sln` file allows us to inform Visual Studio to start Web Api project every time when I start the Test Project (or Test Web Site). Such dependency can't be configured by new `.json` files.

One more example could be important to mention. It's clear that one have a lot of *existing components* and class libraries. It's don't required to rewrite all there at once. To be able to use the old components and to switch to "new world" step by step one need to use old `.sln` file and some old `.xproj` in one solution together with new ASP.NET project. I have to mention [the issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/621), which describes some problems with integration of Class Library in the ASP.NET 5 solution. One see that not all problems are solved now, but it should work in RC2 or in RTM.

My answer is clear not full. I'm sure that the format of `.sln` file and `.xproj` file will be changed soon, but I suppose that we will get some *new* `.json` files, because the existing files (`project.json` for example) don't contains all information, which one would like to have in the solution if one would think about testing and debugging of multiple projects and not only about building the target binaries.

Comment: Really interesting points - I can certainly see that. I had never considered attempting to use non ASP.NET 5 stuff with the new stuff.

Comment: @GraemeMiller: I'm sure that one will see soon new more clear format of solution and project files, which will be supported by Visual Studio, but the old one will be continued be supported for a long time too. I'm sure that the new good concept can't be the real solution for large companies. One need to safe old investments and to have slowly but safe migration way.