# If an ASP.NET 5 project/solution has no SLN file how do I open it in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

As per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34337569/is-sln-file-required-by-visual-studio-for-asp-net-5-project-can-it-just-use-gl)

I have established that ASP.NET 5 doesn't require an SLN file but VS may require it to allow opening?

I know if I create a ASP.NET 5 project outside of Visual Studio it will not have an SLN file. What is the expected way to open such a Solution in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1? What happens if the solution contains multiple projects?

Comment: SLN files still exist.. You could open your xproj and click save sln from there.

Comment: Ok so I can see I can open an xproj and click SaveAll it offers to make a SLN file. I was ignoring the xproj and trying to open global.json or project.json directly. What happens if Solution contained multiple projects?

Comment: Is an xproj not a VS artifact though? Would I have created one of those I hadn't created the project in VS? As per here http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/projects.html xproj is a VS thing - so it wouldn't exist if solution was created by a non VS developer

Comment: xproj and sln are VS artifacts. They are not created with the `generator-aspnet` from [tag:yeoman]. They are not required since global.json represent your solution and project.json represent your project.

Comment: Ok - so we can't use Xproj to open in VS as it won't exist. There must be some sort of tooling story that will make this work

Answer (score 3):

You open the .xproj-file (same as the csproj predecessor). When that is done, you can use `File > Save All` to generate a .sln file.

If there is no xproj present for the project, as it is not required by asp.net 5. Then you can create a new project in Visual Studio with the desired name and then simply drop your files in the Solution Explorer. After that `File > Save All` and you also have a .sln-file.

Comment: Yeah I kind of assume I could basically do that. Just hoping there was a better way - tooling extension etc

Comment: You can drop all files at once. It's not really *that* much of a hassle.

Comment: Yeah I know - I don't mind - just trying to explain to clients how great ASP.NET 5 is and looking at eliminating obstacles