# Why is Visual Studio 2015 Community asking me to create a .sln for .NET Core app?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I just downloaded the Contoso sample application located in https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnet/data/ef-mvc/intro/samples/cu-final and I opened it in Visual Studio Community 2015. When I tried to close Visual Studio, it asked me if I want to save the file ContosoUniversity.sln.

Isn't the new .NET Core and VS 2015 doing away with .sln files? Why is it asking me this? I chose Yes so what do I do if I was supposed to say No?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34337569/is-sln-file-required-by-visual-studio-for-asp-net-5-project-can-it-just-use-gl

Comment: @JimHewitt looked at that link but it still leaves me wondering how the new multi-platform idea surrounding .net core still involves visual studio artifacts like .sln files. Does this mean I won't be able to open this solution in Visual Studio Code? I'm using VS 2015 Community.

Comment: According to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics) you can, but I have not tried it.